# Map an ADLS Gen2 storage to a a windows drive

Tags: azure-blob-storage

A colleague of mine is claiming that it is not possible to map an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 store to a mapped drive in Windows. I'm not a specialist on this, but I'm very skeptical on this statement, as I see elsewhere that this should be possible: it is possible to connect a file share to a Blob storage, and to map a drive to a file share. And ADLS Gen2 is built on top of Azure Blob Storage.

Could anyone clarify this for me? Either why it would not be possible or, if it is, how it can be done?